# LocalDateTime format ok in JSON, not ok in database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, datetime-format, java-time

I want to format date-times in a SpringBoot REST API I'm building in the format `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"`. So I've put it in a global constant:

```java
public static final String GLOBAL_DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS";
```

and I've annotated my DTO's `LocalDateTime` field:

```java
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = GLOBAL_DATE_TIME_PATTERN)
@JsonFormat(pattern = GLOBAL_DATE_TIME_PATTERN)
private LocalDateTime createdDateTime;
```

as well as my entity's field:

```java
@Column(name = "created_date_time", updatable = false)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = GLOBAL_DATE_TIME_PATTERN)
@JsonFormat(pattern = GLOBAL_DATE_TIME_PATTERN)
@CreatedDate
protected LocalDateTime createdDateTime;
```

I've `POST`-ed a few payloads (they're supposed to represent tasks in the form of cards), and I'm getting the `createdDateTime` field formatted exactly as I want it in response or after a `GET` by ID:

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "JC2",
    .
    .
    .
    "createdDateTime": "29/07/2023 01:07:49.096",
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Unfortunately, in my database (MySQL) the date is formatted differently:

```sql
mysql> select id, created_date_time from card;
+----+----------------------------+
| id | created_date_time          |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | 2023-07-29 00:57:51.083969 |
|  2 | 2023-07-29 01:07:49.096333 |
+----+----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to have the database date/times formatted as `GLOBAL_DATE_TIME_PATTERN` dictates. I'm wondering whether the `@CreatedDate` annotation is in any way interfering. Grateful for any help.

Comment: You really should be making use of time zones and ISO standardised formats - the “format” of the date in the database should otherwise be irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

Mysql column and data need to be in string, not date type if you want to store in d/m/Y format. BUT keep in mind that you won't be able to perform date/time-related queries efficiently. If you need to perform queries based on the date/time values, it's better to keep the standard datetime format in the database and format the values as needed when fetching them for display in the frontend or API response.

OR

You can use this query,

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(created_date_time,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s.%f') AS created_date_time_formatted
from card;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please understand that `@CreatedDate`,`@DateTimeFormat` or `@JsonFormat` is not responsible for formatting dates in the database.

`@JsonFormat` used for formatting dates during JSON serialization/deserialization, so it's responsible for formatting dates in the API responses, not in the DB.

`@CreatedDate` used for automatically populating the `createdDateTime` field with the current date & time when a new entity is persisted & again has nothing to do with format in the DB.

When a `LocalDateTime` obj is persisted to the DB, it gets converted to the corresponding date & time data type supported by the DB (like `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`) & they are stored in their own internal representation.  MySql by default retrieves & displays `DATETIME` columns in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.

As other answer had pointed out, you can simply change the format in which you retrieve the `DATETIME` column (like by using `DATE_FORMAT()` func) or you could store it as `VARCHAR` in your `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS` format. But storing as a `VARCHAR` is **not recommended**.